# Visual Studio Change Text Box On Another Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am making a program where when you enter a Profile Name (in TextBox1) and click the add button. I want it to add whatever was entered TextBox1 to another text box (TextBox2) on another form open in the background. The other form is called addsnake (don't ask). I get no build errors but the text box on the addsnake form (TextBox2) doesn't change. This is my code in the button press:

```
        Dim newsnake As New addsnake
        TextBox1.Text = newsnake.TextBox2.Text
```

And yes I do have both text boxes set to Public.

**First Form (*newprofile***)

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission
Public Class NewProfile
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Dim newsnake As addsnake

#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        newsnake = New addsnake
        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    End Sub

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents Button2 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents OleDbSelectCommand1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Friend WithEvents OleDbInsertCommand1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Friend WithEvents OleDbUpdateCommand1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Friend WithEvents OleDbDeleteCommand1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Friend WithEvents OleDbConnection1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Friend WithEvents OleDbDataAdapter1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Friend WithEvents Dataset11 As TestFeedingChart.Dataset1
    Public WithEvents TextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.OleDbSelectCommand1 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Me.OleDbConnection1 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Me.OleDbInsertCommand1 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Me.OleDbUpdateCommand1 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Me.OleDbDeleteCommand1 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Me.OleDbDataAdapter1 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Me.Dataset11 = New TestFeedingChart.Dataset1
        CType(Me.Dataset11, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(16, 8)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(104, 16)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Label1.Text = "Enter Profile Name:"
        '
        'TextBox1
        '
        Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 8)
        Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
        Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(208, 20)
        Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(248, 32)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 24)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 6
        Me.Button1.Text = "Add"
        '
        'Button2
        '
        Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(136, 32)
        Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
        Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 24)
        Me.Button2.TabIndex = 7
        Me.Button2.Text = "Cancel"
       '
       'OleDbSelectCommand1
       '
       Me.OleDbSelectCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT id, ProfileName FROM Profile"
       Me.OleDbSelectCommand1.Connection = Me.OleDbConnection1
       '
       'OleDbConnection1
       '
       Me.OleDbConnection1.ConnectionString = "Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=;Jet OLEDB:Database L" & _
       "ocking Mode=1;Data Source=""C:\Data\Database.mdb"";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Provide" & _
       "r=""Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"";Jet OLEDB:System database=;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;persi" & _
       "st security info=False;Extended Properties=;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:Encry" & _
       "pt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Lo" & _
       "cale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;User ID=Adm" & _
       "in;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1"
       '
       'OleDbInsertCommand1
       '
       Me.OleDbInsertCommand1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profile(ProfileName) VALUES (?)"
       Me.OleDbInsertCommand1.Connection = Me.OleDbConnection1
       Me.OleDbInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("ProfileName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar, 50, "ProfileName"))
       '
       'OleDbUpdateCommand1
       '
       Me.OleDbUpdateCommand1.CommandText = "UPDATE Profile SET ProfileName = ? WHERE (id = ?) AND (ProfileName = ? OR ? IS NU" & _
       "LL AND ProfileName IS NULL)"
       Me.OleDbUpdateCommand1.Connection = Me.OleDbConnection1
       Me.OleDbUpdateCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("ProfileName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar, 50, "ProfileName"))
       Me.OleDbUpdateCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("Original_id", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "id", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing))
       Me.OleDbUpdateCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("Original_ProfileName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar, 50, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "ProfileName", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing))
       Me.OleDbUpdateCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("Original_ProfileName1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar, 50, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "ProfileName", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing))
       '
       'OleDbDeleteCommand1
       '
       Me.OleDbDeleteCommand1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Profile WHERE (id = ?) AND (ProfileName = ? OR ? IS NULL AND ProfileN" & _
       "ame IS NULL)"
       Me.OleDbDeleteCommand1.Connection = Me.OleDbConnection1
       Me.OleDbDeleteCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("Original_id", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 0, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "id", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing))
       Me.OleDbDeleteCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("Original_ProfileName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar, 50, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "ProfileName", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing))
       Me.OleDbDeleteCommand1.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("Original_ProfileName1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar, 50, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, False, CType(0, Byte), CType(0, Byte), "ProfileName", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, Nothing))
       '
       'OleDbDataAdapter1
       '
       Me.OleDbDataAdapter1.DeleteCommand = Me.OleDbDeleteCommand1
       Me.OleDbDataAdapter1.InsertCommand = Me.OleDbInsertCommand1
       Me.OleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = Me.OleDbSelectCommand1
       Me.OleDbDataAdapter1.TableMappings.AddRange(New System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping() {New System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping("Table", "Profile", New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping() {New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping("id", "id"), New System.Data.Common.DataColumnMapping("ProfileName", "ProfileName")})})
       Me.OleDbDataAdapter1.UpdateCommand = Me.OleDbUpdateCommand1
       '
       'Dataset11
       '
       Me.Dataset11.DataSetName = "Dataset1"
       Me.Dataset11.Locale = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
       '
       'NewProfile
       '
       Me.AutoScaleBaseSize = New System.Drawing.Size(5, 13)
       Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(354, 68)
       Me.ControlBox = False
       Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
       Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
       Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
       Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
       Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
       Me.MaximizeBox = False
       Me.Name = "NewProfile"
       Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent
       Me.Text = "Add New Profile"
       CType(Me.Dataset11, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
       Me.ResumeLayout(False)

   End Sub

#End Region

Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub


Private Sub RefreshData()
    Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\Data\Database.mdb ;Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x;")
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [id], " & _
                                         "ProfileName AS [Name]" & _
                                         "FROM Profile ORDER BY id", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cnn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (TextBox1.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a profile name.")
    Else

        Dim newsnake As addsnake
        Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\Database.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;")
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If
        Dim SQL As String

        '("SELECT ProfileName FROM Profile WHERE ProfileName = TextBox1")
        'TextBox2.Text = SQL
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profile(ProfileName) " & _
                          "VALUES ('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If Not IsNothing(newsnake) Then
            newsnake.UpdateText = TextBox1.Text
        End If

        cnn.Close()
        Me.Close()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub OleDbDataAdapter1_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub NewProfile_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim oForm As addsnake
    oForm = New addsnake
    oForm.Show()
    oForm = Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```

**Second Form (*addsnake*)**

```
Public Class addsnake
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    End Sub

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents Button2 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Public WithEvents TextBox2 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.TextBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(8, 8)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(112, 23)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Label1.Text = "Snake Name/Morph:"
        '
        'TextBox1
        '
        Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(112, 8)
        Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
        Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(288, 20)
        Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(296, 64)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(96, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 2
        Me.Button1.Text = "Add"
        '
        'Button2
        '
        Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(8, 64)
        Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
        Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(104, 23)
        Me.Button2.TabIndex = 3
        Me.Button2.Text = "Cancel"
        '
        'Label2
        '
        Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(8, 32)
        Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
        Me.Label2.TabIndex = 4
        Me.Label2.Text = "Profile:"
        '
        'TextBox2
        '
        Me.TextBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(112, 32)
        Me.TextBox2.Name = "TextBox2"
        Me.TextBox2.ReadOnly = True
        Me.TextBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(288, 20)
        Me.TextBox2.TabIndex = 5
        Me.TextBox2.Text = "-No Profile Selected-"
        Me.TextBox2.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center
        '
        'addsnake
        '
        Me.AutoScaleBaseSize = New System.Drawing.Size(5, 13)
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(402, 92)
        Me.ControlBox = False
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.Name = "addsnake"
        Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent
        Me.Text = "Add New Snake"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

#End Region

    Public Property UpdateText() As String
        Get
            Return TextBox2.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            TextBox2.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Sub RefreshData()
        Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\Data\Database.mdb ;Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x;")
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [id], " & _
                                         "SnakeName AS [Name]" & _
                                         "FROM Snake ORDER BY id", cnn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        cnn.Close()

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (TextBox1.Text = "") Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a snake name.")
        Else
            Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\Database.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;")
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If

            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Snake(SnakeName) " & _
                          "VALUES ('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cnn.Close()
            Me.Close()
            MsgBox("Snake Succefully Added! :D")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: if you want to assign the TextBox1 value to TextBox2, then  you have to use like, newsnake.TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your addsnake form and not showing it, it is not the form that you have visible on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, it looks like you are creating a separate `addsnake` Form, without showing it to make it visible most likely it is not the one that you want to see your text in. You need to keep a `Class` Scoped instance variable to hold the instance of `addsnake` that you made visible earlier. Also as Viji stated you are assigning the value of newsnake.TextBox2 to TextBox1 not the other way as you stated that you wanted. Something like this example should give you an idea.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim newsnake As addsnake

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        newsnake = New addsnake
        newsnake.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not IsNothing(newsnake) Then
            newsnake.TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
        End If
   End Sub

End Class
```

But personally I would not make any of my form's internals public, I would prefer to use properties to access the internals something like this, I am just showing the changes.

```
Public Class addsnake
    Public Property UpdateText As String
        Get
            Return TextBox2.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            TextBox2.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**Form1**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not IsNothing(newsnake) Then
        newsnake.UpdateText = TextBox1.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Edit after seeing your code.

What I noticed is you are creating the addsnake Form called oForm that is visible when you load  your NewProfile Form, even though you set the object to nothing it is still active and visible.  When you click your button you create a newsnake object of your addsnake Form which will mask the class level newsnake you created in the Forms constructor which you do not make visible by showing it therefore you will never see the TextBox change. I am uncertain exactly what your program flow is but it looks like you are wanting the program to close after the last Form is close because you are closing your startup Form after you update newsnake.

My question right now is what do you want `oForm` to do? is that the form you wish to see the TextBox changed in? if so you need to make it a Module scoped variable instead of newsnake and use that. If not you are newing up newsnake in the Forms constructor like I showed but you are also creating a local newsnake variable in your Button1 click eventhandler which is null, you need to get rid of that line and show the newsnake Form somewhere.

Try changing your Button click event to this.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (TextBox1.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a profile name.")
    Else

        Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\Database.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;")
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If
        Dim SQL As String

        '("SELECT ProfileName FROM Profile WHERE ProfileName = TextBox1")
        'TextBox2.Text = SQL
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profile(ProfileName) " & _
                          "VALUES ('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If Not IsNothing(newsnake) Then
            newsnake.UpdateText = TextBox1.Text
            newsnake.show()                     `note change
        End If

        cnn.Close()
        Me.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Put your code in, no build errors but the text box never changes. I even tried the second option you put in.

Comment: @JamesConroy. I tested both examples on my computer before I posted them and they worked correctly. Not sure what you are doing without seeing your implementation.

Comment: @JamesConroy I can see what you are doing and what your error is, I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, you have three addsnake Forms being referenced in your program, the Class level newsnake, the local variable newsnake and the local variable oForm. see if my answer makes any sense to you